# Освободить память от пользовательского элемента

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Есть код пользовательского TextBox (ReadOnlyTextBox), который размещается неоднократно на форме с помощью панели элементов:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ReadOnlyTextBox : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public ReadOnlyTextBox()
    {
        this.ReadOnly = true;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.GotFocus += TextBoxGotFocus;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        HideCaret(this.Handle);
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно освободить память от "this.GotFocus += TextBoxGotFocus;", надо прописывать "this.GotFocus -= TextBoxGotFocus;" в коде формы?

Comment: Можете ничего не делать, такая подписка не повлияет на возможность удаления элемента сборщиком мусора

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно отменять подписку в этом случае.

Смотрите, подписки на события же не просто так мешают сборщику мусора - а потому что создают дополнительные ссылки.

Рассмотрим такой код:

```
a.Foo += b.Bar
```

После выполнения этого кода у объекта `a` окажется ссылка на объект `b`.

В каком случае эта ссылка помешает сборке мусора? В том случае когда время жизни объекта `b` должно быть меньше времени жизни объекта `a`.

В вашем же случае что объект `a`, что объект `b` - это один и тот же this. Такой обработчик события никогда не вызовет утечку памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто по идее дописать `Dispose`, так как `TextBox` : `TextBoxBase` : `Control` : `IDisposable`

```
public class ReadOnlyTextBox : TextBox
{
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

  public ReadOnlyTextBox()
  {
    this.ReadOnly = true;
    this.BackColor = Color.White;
    this.GotFocus += TextBoxGotFocus;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
  }

  private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    HideCaret(this.Handle);
  }

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    this.GotFocus -= TextBoxGotFocus;
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!